# How can I get rid of double \ character (\\) which I keep in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, unicode-string

I have some data in my MsSql database and send them to my Android app by Csharp Web Apis. There some unicode characters in nvarchar fields. There are in the middle of the string data. For example: 'F\u2081 is greater than F\u2082'

The data keeps going to the mobile app as "F\u2081 is greater than F\u2082" . So the unicode characters are never displayed successfully.

I searched and tried many methods but no success so far. 
You can test and see the result of the web api (post)
http://www.kelimex.com.tr/teogapi/api/Fen

In the result view, "message" field data comes from the database. 
But the "explanation" field data is entered by me in the source code of web api.

As you will see the is no problem in the field "explanation". But "message" field keeps showing up incorrectly.

Does anyone have any experience on this issue?

Here is the csharp code which pulls the data from Sql and returns a list for the web api. Currently there is no encoding-decoding-etc... None of them worked anyway.

```
    public List<Result> test()
    {
        List<Result> list = new List<Result>();
        if (ConnectToDB())
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("__tm_test", conn);
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                da.Fill(ds, "ds");
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    Result item = new Result();

                    item.statusCode = 1;
                    item.status = true;
                    item.message = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FieldNVarchar"].ToString();
                    item.explanation = "F\u2081 is greater than F\u2082";

                    list.Add(item);
                }
                ds.Dispose();
                da.Dispose();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 You should use HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode and HttpUtility.UrlEncode for text you are setting a variable. Please check the below example:

    //Encode a text 
    var myText = HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(MyText)

    //And Decode text you are getting

   var MyTextNew = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text)
```

Comment: I tried using HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode and HttpUtility.UrlEncode UTF-8 in the web api, and parse the data using URLDecoder.decode UTF-8, UTF-16 and Unicode in Android java. No success.